# rosrun not finding executable

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, rosrun, ros-groovy, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am at the "Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)" step in the tutorial and `catkin_make` works and i can manually run both `talker` and `listener` correctly from `~/code/catkin_ws/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/` where the binaries are. The issue is that rosrun can't find them:

```
$ rosrun beginner_tutorials talker                       
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker below /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/build/beginner_tutorials/catkin_generated/stamps/beginner_tutorials
```

I do not understand why it's not looking in the correct place as the ros path looks correct to me.

```
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH                                 
/home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Edit:

```
$ rospack profile
0.020060   /opt/ros/groovy/share
0.009610   /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws
0.005365   /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/build
0.005278 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp
0.005180 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp/ros
0.002913 * /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/devel
0.002156   /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/build/beginner_tutorials
0.001267   /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/build/serial
0.001108 * /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/devel/share
0.001090 * /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/build/beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles
0.000988 * /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/devel/lib
0.000923 * /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/build/serial/CMakeFiles
0.000882 * /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/src
0.000745   /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/build/beginner_tutorials/catkin_generated
0.000624   /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/build/kbot
0.000565 * /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles
0.000561 * /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/src/kbot
0.000554 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp/ros/std_msgs
0.000554   /home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/build/kbot/kbot_bridge
0.000468 * /opt/ros/groovy/share/common-lisp/ros/sensor_msgs
```

OS: Arch Linux. Kernel: 3.8.5-1-ARCH x86_64. ROS: Desktop Install built from source.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60286/rosrun-not-finding-executable/) by [exuvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4643/exuvo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually `$ rospack profile` helps. As I understand it crawls through the directories in `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and updates the list of available packages.

P.S. How did you initialize the catkin workspace? The path looks truncated, i.e. it should be `/home/exuvo/code/catkin_ws/src` with `src` at the end, at least on my system it is like this. Just in case here is the [tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [exuvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4643/exuvo/) on 2013-04-09**:
My code is in ~/code/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials as it should and the symlink to catkins toplevel CMakeLists exists in src. When i run catkin_make in ~/code/catkin_ws it creates the build and devel folders and find search gave me the path to the working executables.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-04-09**:
So, have you tried `rospack profile`?

**Comment by [exuvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4643/exuvo/) on 2013-04-09**:
I edited the main post with the output, rosrun still not working. Should i somehow exclude the build folder? Do I need to run something more than catkin_make for rosrun to find things?

**Comment by [exuvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4643/exuvo/) on 2013-04-09**:
I found the error! I had missed the last line in the link you gave "source devel/setup.bash". I was only sourcing the global and adding the ros path manually. I thought you meant "catkin_init_workspace" when you wrote initialize workspace which i had done.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-04-09**:
Great! One question though - did you initialize catkin workspace in `catkin_ws/src` or somewhere else? Maybe that is the effect of not sourcing `devel/setup.bash`, however, `catkin_generated` shouldn't be anywhere in `catkin_ws/src`, but in the `catkin_ws/build`.

**Comment by [exuvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4643/exuvo/) on 2013-04-10**:
I believe I initialized the catkin workspace in catkin_ws/src. All catkin_generated folders are under catkin_ws/build, I must have confused you somewhere. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just as a heads up for those who didn't read the docs (like I did), you will want to add your targets AFTER you call `catkin_package()` - otherwise your binaries will not be put in the right spot.

---

Originally posted by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) with karma: 174 on 2013-09-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kilmarnock](https://answers.ros.org/users/1720/kilmarnock/) on 2016-04-18**:
+1, man. This leads to unexpected search paths and tears.

**Comment by [ZQ.Jones](https://answers.ros.org/users/28254/zq.jones/) on 2017-05-12**:
+1, correct answer

**Comment by [ashutosh08](https://answers.ros.org/users/44302/ashutosh08/) on 2020-02-13**:
+1 correct answer thanks